# Creating adjacency matrix in LaTeX

Tags: diagrams

How can I create an adjacency matrix like this in LaTeX as a vectorized image?

[image]

Comment: See the `pmatrix` environment from `amsmath`.

Comment: see https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics#Matrices_and_arrays

Comment: How can I download it as image ? The pmatrix that I have created ?

Comment: You can use the standalone documentclass to produce a small pdf file containing just your matrix. If you need a (rasterized) image, you will have to render that out (look through the 'save as' dialogue, options depend on you system). If you need a .svg file, an option may be to go through Inkscape and enter your matrix there.

Comment: I need to make the pmatrix look bigger. It is looking very small when I download it as pdf and I'm facing scaling issues when I'm including this pdf on my file.

Comment: Suffice it to say, the PDF can be scaled to any size.  Problems only occur when you rasterize it.  Even acrobat likes to rasterize rather coarsely.  A graphics editor (like Gimp) has more flexibility.  You might try using \scalebox (grphicx package) inside the standalone to make the original bigger.

Answer (score 1):

Using `\documentclass{standalone}` avoids the large area of white space that you would get around the matrix if you used `\documentclass{article}`.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\begin{pmatrix}
    2&1&0&0&1&0\\
    1&0&1&0&1&0\\
    0&1&0&1&0&0\\
    0&0&1&0&1&1\\
    1&1&0&1&0&0\\
    0&0&0&1&0&0\\
\end{pmatrix}$
\end{document}
```

[image]